# What does this MacOS/X dialog mean?

Tags: macos, privacy, gatekeeper

My mom recently started seeing the dialog in the attached photo whenever she tries to launch her favorite video game (which she downloaded from Big Fish games a few weeks ago; she's running MacOS Big Sur / 11.6, if that's important).

Does anyone know what would cause this dialog to appear, or have any information on how seriously we should take it?  i.e. does it mean that Apple has found that the game contains spyware, or is there some other reasoning behind the dialog?

For the record, the text in the dialog is:

> "CaveQuest2CEMacBFGEng" has been blocked because it may reduce your privacy and lower the security of your Mac.  You should move it to the Trash.  [This file was downloaded on an unknown date.]   [Cancel] [Move to Trash]

[image: MacOS privacy warning]

Comment: macOS indeed thinks that the file contains spyware/malware. Have you tried moving it to the trash and downloading it again? Note that, according to https://www.bigfishgames.com/games/18519/cave-quest-2/?mac&lang=en, the game is only supported on macOS 10.15 and 10.14.